# Is there an intuition or analytic explanation for the multi-taper form of power spectrogram derivatives using Slepian windows?

Tags: fft, audio, derivative

I am using $x_k(t,f)$, the FFT of the 1-d signal x weighted by the k'th Slepian function in a window around time t. k goes from 1 to K.

This allows defining the multi-taper spectrogram:
$$S(t,f) = \sum_k x_k * x_{k}^{'}$$

for a given direction in the (t,f) plane (t=time, f=frequency) whose angle with the t axis is theta there is a formula:
$$\nabla_{\theta} S = \Re(z)$$

where $\nabla_{\theta}$ is the directional derivative in direction theta and

$$z = \sum_k x_k * x_{k+1}^{'}  $$

Why should this hold?
(It empirically works for speech sounds)

My intuition is that this has to do with the similarity between the (k+1)'th Slepian function and the derivative of the k'th function.

Using the FFT of a multiplication as a convolution of FFTs (here of x and the window function) and the derivative rule for convolutions it seems that differentiating S(t,f) should factor such that the derivative is eventually only applied to the FFT of the Slepian function.. but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I tied to clean up your formulas but please double check whether they are correct.